# Strange symbol with \bigstar

Tags: symbols

I would like to insert a star into my latex document.
So, i tried this command: `\bigstar`

But, i get this result instead of a star:

[image: Result]

Do you know how i can fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Please add a complete small document that shows the problem. `\bigstar` is not defined by default in LaTex and would make no output, just an error message, so you must have used some package or definition, or you got an error message?

Answer (score 11):

Try including the `amssymb` package and using the math environment. The following code should produce a black star as shown below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    $\bigstar$
\end{document}
```

[image]